# What does "broadcast" mean here?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), using a blueprint, Roland shows a plan to defeat the Machines that are attempting to enter Zion:

> Roland:  The machines have taken Junction 21. The way I see it, if we drop down
> from **broadcast** here...intersect 153, we might surprise them. We'll go first, hammer as deep
> as we can, then blow our EMP.

**What does "broadcast" mean here?**

Answer (score 23):

'Broadcast' is a slang way of referring to 'broadcast *depth*' or 'broadcast *level*', basically [the elevation at which the Zionese hoverships are able to hack into the Matrix with a pirated signal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95390/20774).

> **Morpheus:** *You believe it's the year 1999 when in fact it's closer to 2199. I can't tell you exactly what year it is because we honestly
> don't know. There's nothing I can say that will explain it for you,
> Neo. Come with me. See for yourself. This is my ship, the
> Nebuchadnezzar. It's a hovercraft. This is the main deck. **This is the
> core where we broadcast our pirate signal and hack into the Matrix.**
> Most of my crew you already know. This is Apoc, Switch, and Cypher.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Matrix - Transcript](https://sfy.ru/transcript/matrix_ts)</sup></sub>

and

> **Morpheus:** *Dozer, when you’re done, bring the ship **up to broadcast depth.** We’re going in. I’m taking Neo to see her.*

and

> **Niobe:** *We’re gonna do what Commander Lock ordered us to do. **We’ll evacuate broadcast level** and return to Zion.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Matrix: Reloaded - Transcript](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 10):

"Broadcast" here refers to broadcast depth. The level below the surface of the planet that the inhabitants of Zion have to reach to in order to hack into the matrix.

As explained futher in here; [Why not enter the Matrix from Zion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95383/why-not-enter-the-matrix-from-zion)

The section quoted is a battle plan to move down from the broadcast depth, closer to Zion into the attacking machine army and detonate the EMP.